# Can I include bank statements from middle of month in UK visitor visa application?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, premium-services

I'll be applying for UK standard visitor visa in the next few months, I'm going to upload online bank statements with it. My question is does the online bank statements have to start on the 1st date of each month?

e.g if I'm applying on 22nd Feb, can I get an online statement from 20th September- 20th February? or does it has to be from 1st September to 1st February?

Comment: My UK bank statements do not cover a calendar month so I imagine they will not be surprised.

Comment: Thanks, mdewey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter when the statement periods begin and end, as long as they cover the entire period. Many banks do not align their statements with the month ends.

Comment: Thanks, DJClayworth.